# Long load time for Wcf Ria Domain Service

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, domainservices

**The Problem, in short**
I am encountering lag (resulting in a time out) when calling a domain service query.

**What am I doing ?**
I have a Silverlight 4 application. The app depends heavily on Domain services.

**Replication**
Everything starts off fine. The app loads up and runs authentication against a domain service a-ok. I then can loads a collection of "contacts" from the "contactsdomainservice" without serious lag or hang ups.

The problem occurs when I run a query from the "playersdomainservice". This service is nearly *identical* to the "contactsdomainservice". It even uses the same Linq-2-sql data context. The silverlight sends out the request, however, the request does not reach the service until well after the client has already timed out. (the service executes perfectly btw).

**My question is. What is broken, and how can I debug this.**

**Fiddler 2**
When using fiddler i use localhost.:6000 (I add a period to the local host). When doing this **the problem goes away**.

**Wcf Trace**
Looking at the Wcf Trace logs, the player's request and responce apears with no anomolies. The request / responce execute in under 100ms.

That said, I do see some warnings in other requests.

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>524312</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Warning">0</SubType>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2010-11-07T17:58:27.8435791Z" />
    <Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{5f3870a6-b186-43be-9aab-6f27044d653a}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="WebDev.WebServer40" ProcessID="7424" ThreadID="8" />
    <Channel />
  </System>
  <ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem>
    <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Warning">
      <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.EvaluationContextNotFound.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
      <Description>Configuration evaluation context not found.</Description>
      <AppDomain>4bf2d999-1-129336262987410584</AppDomain>
    </TraceRecord>
  </DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Comment: Update. I have a duplex service running. When I turn off the duplex service the problem goes away. This may be a maximum connections issue. I will go experiment now.